# flow redux action property not found

Tags: redux, flowtype

[image]

Flow errors out on the property `ruleId`.
If I hover over `action`, it displays the right type for the action including the property `ruleId`.

Is there a reason why Flow barks on me here?

```
export const ADVANCED_RULES_ADD_NEW_RULE: string = "ADVANCED_RULES_ADD_NEW_RULE";
export type AdvancedRulesAddNewRule = {
  type: string, 
  predicateId: InternalId,
  ruleId: InternalId,
  direction: Direction
};

export type Action = AdvancedRulesAddNewRule | AnotherAction | SomeOtherAction;
```

The type seems to be correctly defined, I have no idea why the property `ruleId` isn't recognized.

Comment: What's the full error message say?

Comment: property `ruleId`Property not found in object type.
Does it matter that I defined the type of my action as "string". And export a literal string as the value of the action?

Comment: @saadq weird  if type `export type AdvancedRulesAddNewRule = {
  type: 'ADVANCED_RULES_ADD_NEW_RULE', 
  predicateId: InternalId,
  ruleId: InternalId,
  direction: Direction
}`; 
it recognises the property... magic..